# GPS Location of contacts

Tags: android, gps

i have a code that finds the location of my phone but i want to find the location of contacts stored in a database.Can anyone help how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a few possibilities where this can work:

1) You have the address of the contact stored:
  In that case use a geocoder location service: e.g  Google, Apple
  But this is then of course not the current location.

2) The contact has the same - your - application installed and running, and this app is able to   communicate the current position regulary to a server, where you query it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an address field stored with the contact just read it; otherwise it is *not* possible with a straight forward solution

Comment: The maximum you can get from the mobile number is the country or area code if it is stored, which you can look it up to know the country and maybe the city of the contact

Comment: What will be your input to Google map? a phone number or a person name, how this can be translated to address!?
The only thing that might work, if the contact name is a *business* name that you can search for on YellowPages for example.